# Conjugate gradient method, why is the coefficient matrix not stored?

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, convex-optimization

I've been learning about the conjugate gradient method but I have a hard time understanding the advantages it has in terms of memory usage. If we use the method to solve the linear system $Ax = b$ (or to find the extremum of the quadric defined by $A$ and $b$), apparently $A$ does not have to be stored. But when I look at the Hestenes-Stiefel algorithm I see formulas like:

$\lambda_{i} = r_{i - 1}^{T}r_{i - 1}/p_{i}^{T}Ap_{i}$ and

$r_{i} = r_{i - 1} - \lambda_{i}Ap_{i}$

which clearly contain $A$. So how does this method avoid storing $A$? Is there some sort of approximation of decomposition of $A$ going on? I can't find a concise answer to this question but would like to understand.

Thank you very much in advance for your explanations,

Joshua

Comment: General idea that $x_{n+1} = x_n - \lambda_n p_n$, where $p_n = r_n + \alpha_n p_{n-1}$. So we always keep in memory two vectors. The mathematical reason for it deals with Krylov's space.

Comment: To solve the system you need the information of A, at least in a sparse representation. Otherwise, you would not be able to define problem. Perhaps you confuse the memory advantage  with the comparison to other algorithms, e.g. quasi Newton or Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm, where a Hessian matrix is needed.

Comment: I understand, but don't you need A to compute the 'step size' λ?

Comment: @JoshuaSchroijen In the standard conjugate gradient method A is necessary in some operations. However, this is irrelevant for the memory usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes when solving this sort of problem numerically, we are given a *black-box subfunction* for the operator $A$. It takes $x$ as an input, and gives us the matrix-vector product $Ax$. Sometimes this type of function is called a "Mat-Vec" for short. We know that the underlying process is linear, but we don't necessarily know the entries of $A$.

Sure, if we really needed to, we could feed basis vectors to the mat-vec function to construct $A$ in closed-form. However, this requires extra memory/computation, since you have to construct $A$ before even running your algorithm. Also, depending on the application, computing the mat-vec might actually be faster than performing matrix-vector multiplication (e.g. discrete Fourier transform).

This is one of the huge advantages of the methods you've listed -- they only require the ability to compute a matrix-vector product $Ax$ (and in particular they do not require the ability to access each entry of $A$).